Is there a name for this phenomena: tensor products of representations behave like the underlying group?
Take the Klein four group
$V_4 = \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$:
$$
\{e,a,b,ab\}, \quad \mathrm{with} \quad a^2=b^2=(ab)^2 = e
$$
Over an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0, being Abelian it has only one dimensional irreducible representations. In fact there are exactly four up to isomorphism:
$$
\begin{split}
\rho_1(\{e,a,b,ab\})&=\{1,1,1,1\}\\
\rho_A(\{e,a,b,ab\})&=\{1,1,-1,-1\}\\
\rho_B(\{e,a,b,ab\})&=\{1,-1,1,-1\}\\
\rho_{AB}(\{e,a,b,ab\})&=\{1,-1,-1,1\}
\end{split}
$$
I have very suggestively named these representations, due to the following observation: under tensor products of these representations, the representations themselves behave under the action of the Klein four group:
$$
\rho_1 \otimes \rho_A = \rho_{A}, \quad\rho_A \otimes \rho_B = \rho_{AB}, \quad \rho_{AB} \otimes \rho_A = \rho_{B}, \quad \mathrm{etc.}
$$
Is there a name for this phenomenon? Is it true for all representations of Abelian groups (even Lie groups) over algebraically closed fields of characteristic zero?

The representation theory of a finite group over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero doesn't depend on which of those fields we take, so we might as well work over $\Bbb C$.
If $G$ is finite abelian, then all irreps of $G$ are one-dimensional and may hence be identified with group homomorphisms $G \to \mathrm{GL}_1(\Bbb C)=\Bbb C^\times$. The image is always contained in $S^1$, so we might as well consider homomorphisms $G \to S^1$. Under this identification, tensor products correspond to pointwise multiplication of functions. The group of all such functions (or all irreps) is called the Pontryagin dual group of $G$. For any (locally compact Hausdorff, e.g. discrete) abelian group $H$, the Pontryagin dual group $\widehat{H}$ is defined as $\mathrm{Hom}(H,S^1)$.
Now it is a well-known fact that the Pontryagin dual of a finite abelian group is isomorphic to the group itself, but non-canonically.
So to answer your actual questions: Yes, this is true for all finite Abelian groups over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. The example $G=\Bbb Z$ shows that it doesn't need to hold for infinite groups. (There are uncountably many non-isomorphic irreps of $\Bbb Z$ over $\Bbb C$)
The name for this phenomenon I'd suggest is just that Finite Abelian groups are self-dual, where we can interpret self-dual either via the classical Pontryagin dual or via the "representation theoretic dual", which would be one-dimensional representations under the tensor product (these two duals are isomorphic for finite Abelian gruops, as sketched above).

Great answer! By this same token may we argue the same statement holds for irreducible complex representations of $U(1) \cong S^1$?

@Craig there are only countably many irreducible representations of $S^1$, so $S^1$ can't be self-dual. For any integer $n$, there's the representation $z \mapsto z^n$, corresponding to the fact that the dual group of $S^1$ is $\Bbb Z$

Using continuous homs to $S^1$ to define the dual of a locally compact abelian group, the dual of a compact abelian group is discrete and the dual of a discrete abelian group is compact. Thus if a compact or discrete abelian group $G$ is self-dual then $G$ is compact and discrete. A topological space that is compact and discrete is finite, so $G$ is a finite abelian group. Thus an infinite self-dual loc. compact abelian group is neither compact nor discrete, such as $\mathbf R^n$ where $n \geq 1$.

I see now, thank you!
